# Programmatically add user forum permissions in Drupal

Tags: drupal, acl, drupal-permissions

I'd like to programmatically add **user** forum permissions in Drupal.

Do I have to use ACL module? Is there any example out there, as the documentation is a bit thin?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to restrict, or set CRUD access on a per-forum basis?

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module will work as well.  With the rules module (but not with ACL) you have the option of setting triggers for this to occur.

Comment: There is no option in Rules for adjusting forum permissions. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by programmatically, exactly?

You can define new permissions using hook_perm:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_perm

But the forum module(s) for Drupal should ship with role based permissions to use.

Comment: They should but they don't :)

Comment: There isn't a 'create forum topic' under node or forum permissions?